# How can I keep a log of hours with Emacs Org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How can I log (and sum) an hour count in org mode, where each day I'd write a total of hours?

Note I **do not** want to do time tracking or start a clock. I want to just write # hours per day, and have them added.

EG:

```
* [2014-12-07]
* Hours: 8
* Did this
** a sub section of this
* Did that
** A subsection that
```

The nested list structure does not have to be as I describe here - but the concept is that each DAY has HOURS logged manually, and then I can SUM a group of days.

Comment: I am unaware of whether there is a built-in solution.  A custom solution would require an example of an entire todo entry.  It looks like you've used the stackoverflow outline feature to compose your question (i.e., a star equals a bullet-point) -- perhaps you could indent four spaces and provide a full todo example entry so that a custom solution can be created.  There are substantial differences in terms of dealing with heading, versus drawer, versus notes / items.

Comment: I edited the example list. I'm really new to hacking emacs/org-mode, and I am not stuck on this pattern. I *do* prefer to write a list in a similar fashion, rather than use tables, etc.

Comment: Perhaps an Org-mode spreadsheet would satisfy you ?

Comment: Tables are really inconvenient with lists of text... but I'll have a look more closely at spreadsheets in org-mode.

Comment: How about one heading per client and then each item underneath that main heading is a time-sheet entry for that particular client?  For example, `* John Smith - [2014-11-22 Sat] -- 8.0 hours:  Added new functionality to the function . . . .  - [2014-11-23 Sun] -- 1.5 hours:  Created new database on server . . . .`  An item entry would be designated with a preceding hyphen `-`.  Each item is one line.

Comment: I keep a separate org file for each project, but I see what you mean. I guess the take-homes are that: (a) there is no existing solution, and (b) I'll have to write some Emacs Lisp to do what I want.

Comment: By keeping a format where the numbers line up in columns, there are rectangle commands that add up columns in one fell swoop.  I keep my time-sheets in a flat text file (one for each client):  `8.5 hours -- March 15, 2014 (12:00 p.m. to 9:00 p.m., less one-half hour for lunch):  Meeting with client; prepared x y z.`  I block the region, and hit a function that sends the region to a temporary buffer, strips everything but the hours and strips empty lines, and adds it up, and gives me totals with text that is automatically placed in the kill-ring so that I can paste it into the client's bill.

Comment: I haven't tested this particular function, but adding with rectangles looks something like what is depicted in the following wiki link:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RectangleAdd

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample without a nested structure:

```
* Project

#+COLUMNS: %60ITEM(Work done) %7Hours{total}

#+BEGIN: columnview :hlines 1
| Work done        | Hours |
|------------------+-------|
| * Project        |    23 |
| ** Did this      |     8 |
| ** did that      |     8 |
| ** Did that      |     2 |
| ** Another thing |     5 |
#+END:

** Did this
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Hours:    8
   :END:
** did that
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Hours:    8
   :END:
** Did that
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Hours:    2
   :END:
** Another thing
   :PROPERTIES:
   :Hours:    5
   :END:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number of hours worked each day as a property, then define a column format that sums this up. Here I declare a property called HOURS_WORKED that can be 1-8. Each day you can set the hours worked by setting this property on the day with *ctrl-c ctrl-x p* (**org-set-property**)
The column format specifies that the hours worked are to be totaled. When you look at this in a column view *ctrl-c ctrl-x ctrl-c* (**org-columns** command), you'll see all your totals.

```
* Month
  :PROPERTIES:
  :HOURS_WORKED_ALL:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  :COLUMNS: %25ITEM  %9HOURS_WORKED{:}
  :END:
** Week 1
*** Monday
    :PROPERTIES:
    :HOURS_WORKED: 3
    :END:
*** Tuesday
    :PROPERTIES:
    :HOURS_WORKED: 2
    :END:
```